# Python variable assignment to a function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I've been messing around with an API for a trading website. I'm looking to reduce the amount of calls I have to make (via JSON) to the website so I figure I will assign the results of my call to a variable. My question is this:

```
ETH_balance = polo.return_balances('ETH')
BTC_balance = polo.return_balances('BTC')
```

If I assign the API call `polo.return_balances('ETH')` to `ETH_balance,` is the variable ETH_balance storing the result of the call or the actual call itself?

Does it hinge on if the API call `return`'s the result?

Comment: Always the result.

Comment: Result of call. The `()` is an operator in python.

Comment: If you want to assign a function call to a variable, you use a `lambda`

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated.

Comment: @Barmar or better yet, a full function definition, since assigning lambdas to names is explicitly recommended against in PEP8.

Comment: @Barmar or possibly `functools.partial`

Comment: If the function doesn't return a result, it assigns `None` by default.

Comment: @Jimbo note, a Python  function *always* returns something, that is, Python functions are actual functions and not just routines. If there isn't an explicit `return value` in the function definition, then the function *implicitely returns `None`*

Answer (score 1):

It will store the result of the call.

You can assign functions to variables in python however that will do nothing to reduce the number of calls you are making to the API.

Comment: I don't understand, if it stores the result and I use the variable ETH_Balance later on, shouldn't it return the result of the call and not call the function again?

Comment: It will use the result of the function call, sorry I should have made that more clear.